# Silent Installation of Application in a WiX Source File

Tags: wix, windows-server-2008, silent-installer

I want to install microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable package along with my msi installer. I decide to include it along with my installer as an application file and i wrote a golang code that triggers the silent installation of microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable package. The Service of my application starts only when microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable package is installed. I could see a uninstall option for my application in the Control panel but i couldnt see anything like that for the microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable package. And i am pretty sure that the package is not installed because my application never starts, when i trigger the silent.exe (as an administrator) alone which has the code to silently install the package it gets installed and my application works fine as well. The problem occurs when i try to pack everything in a single msi.

The WiX Source file i wrote to include the silent.exe and also other necessary files i need for my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'>
<?include "CommonVariable.wxi"?>
    <Product Id="*" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Testing" Name="Testing_Name" Version="1.1.1">
        <Package InstallerVersion="111" Compressed="yes" Description = "(x64 Edition) MSI Package"      Comments="(x64 Edition) MSI Package" InstallPrivileges="elevated" Platform="x64"/>
            <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
                <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
                    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                        <Directory Id="MYINSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.foldername)">
                            <!-- Component for list of files to add in Installation location -->
                            <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="{**********-*******-*******-********}">
                                  <File Id="ApplicationFile" Source="silent.exe"  Vital="no" DiskId="1" Hidden="yes"/>
                                  <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="Windows2008R2.exe" Vital="no" DiskId="1" Hidden="yes"/>
                                      <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="Myfiles" Vital="no" DiskId="1" />
                                  <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="Myfiles" Vital="no" DiskId="1" />
                            </Component>

                            ***other Actions for my Application***

                        </Directory>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
                <DirectoryRef Id="MYINSTALLLOCATION">
                  <Component Id="CleanupMainApplicationFolder" Guid="{**********-*******-*******-********}" Win64="yes">
                    <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="MYINSTALLLOCATION" /> 
                  </Component>
                </DirectoryRef>
                <Property Id="MYINSTALLLOCATION" Value="$(var.InstallationLocation)" >
                </Property>
                <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
                    <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
                </Feature>
                <Binary Id="ExeId" SourceFile="silent.exe"/>

                <CustomAction Id="SilentAction" BinaryKey="ExeId" ExeCommand="" Execute='deferred' Return   ='asyncWait' Impersonate='no'/>
                <InstallExecuteSequence>
                    <Custom Action='SilentAction' Before='InstallFinalize'/>
                </InstallExecuteSequence> 

    </Product>
</Wix>
```

The Silent.exe is the golang code i wrote has many functions the part of the code i wrote to silently install the package is as below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    /*........................
    ...........................
    ..........................*/
    /*The code above is for my Different purpose */
    co := exec.Command("C:\\Windows2008R2.exe","/q","/c:\"msiexec","/i","Windows2008R2.msi","/qn","/l*v","C:\\Windows2008R2_x64.log\"")
    if err := co.Run(); err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not allow you to install an application when another application is being installed.So better you can have a MSI for that redistributable package and invoke it separately after the previous installation is done through wmic remote command.